# Is it possible to apply FlowLayout to a JButton within a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, flowlayout

I was completing an assignment for my Java II class and I wanted to position the button underneath the labels in the JFrame. I tried:

```
    button.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

as well as:

```
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
    button.setLayout(flow);
```

and neither affected the position of the button. Positioning the button wasn't required for the assignment so perhaps I am just complicating things for myself, I just thought it would look better centered.

Comment: The component to which the button is added must have a `FlowLayout` (which is the the default layout for a `JPanel` anyway), applying a `FlowLayout` to the button would just influence the layout of the components which are added to the button.

Comment: I suggest reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: if you're trying to position the button, you shouldn't be editing the layout of the button. the layout manager of the parent of the button (in this case the frame) will control how the button is positioned.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should Create an JPanel, then set a layout to the JPanel and then add the buttons you need to that panel, and then add that JPanel to the JFrame so you can change the layout of the buttons with affecting the rest of the components.

```
public class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

private JButton stop_jb;
private JButton start_jb;      

public ControlPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {

    //this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    stop_jb = new JButton("Stop");
    stop_jb .setVisible(true);
    stop_jb .setActionCommand("stop");
    this.add(stop_jb );

    start_jb = new JButton("Start");        
    start_jb .setVisible(true);
    start_jb .setActionCommand("Start");
    this.add(start_jb );
```